# How to receive childs of childs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to skip one child encapsulation to get access to the grand-child directly.

```
this.props.children.map((x) => ...);
```

The example above is used to loop over the childs of a parent...
But how do i iterate over the childs of childs ?

I tried to access the childs of childs, but this gave me a undefined exception.

```
this.props.children.map((x) => return x.children);
```

Comment: Use [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) or [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/why-use-react-redux#why-use-react-redux) to exchange data between scattered components. Based on this and your previous post, standard techniques are starting to get painful ;)

Comment: Could you show the tree? Maybe you need to apply recursion to get last level child. because children may have many children.

Comment: use *React.Children.toArray(this.props.children).map((x...* instead of *this.props.children.map((x) => ...);*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.props.children` is not an array. you should transform it before apply map transformation.

```
let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children)
children.map((x) => return x.props.children);
```

Also you have to access children props to access to its children.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! This throws me a undefined exception aswell... says props are undefined.

Comment: The problem is that this.props.children is not an array. You should transform to an array.

`let children = React.Children.toArray(this.props.children);`

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

```
const level2Child = this.props.children.map(child => {
        return child.props.children;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
this.props.children.map((x) => return x.children);
```

use:

```
this.props.children.map((x) => return x.props.children);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard for you to get exact code of people which solve your problem. Rather I would suggest you to take approach of 'recursion'.